# Is it possible to use Azure Data Factory copy activity to copy the data result of a view into a table?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have staging tables in my SQL Server database, views that transform and combine those tables and final tables that I create from the result data of the views.

I could automatise the process by creating a stored process that would truncate the final table and insert the data from the view.

I want to know if it's possible to do this operation with an Azure Data Factory copy activity using the view as source and the table as sink.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I feel like the real question here isn't "is this possible?" (as then the answer is just "yes" or "no"), and more, if this is possible, how do you achieve this. This could, therefore, be voted as "needs more focus", as often questions phrased like as "is this possible?" often are as they aren't asking the *real* question, nor have the focus of the requirements needed to be specific and on topic.

Comment: Did you try anythings? Data Factory support SQL Server/database view as the source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF does support SQL server as source as well as sink.
So there are 2 ways:

1. You can use copy activity with the view as your source and table as the destination
2. You can use stored procedure activity wherein you have all data ingestion/transformations logics within stored procedure and call the stored procedure